# Updating a timer interrupt continuously as global time in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, slider, interactive

I'm trying to import a timer interrupt class called 'perpetualTimer'into the file `ChangingPlot`, and I'm having troubles doing that. Essentially this code allows a user to use a slider to move a blue marker on the screen and try following a graph (in this case I'm using a logarithmic graph). The y coordinate of the marker is controlled by a [GUI slider widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPOYf.png) and I want the x coordinate to be controlled by a continuous time step that I am defining in the time class. The update function in `ChangingPlot`updates both these values and this is where I'm having troubles continuously importing and updating the time. Can anyone please help?

**The code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from timer import time
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

from timer import time
from threading import Timer,Thread,Event

class perpetualTimer():

   def __init__(self,t,hFunction):
      self.t=t
      self.hFunction = hFunction
      self.thread = Timer(self.t,self.handle_function)

   def handle_function(self):
      self.hFunction()
      self.thread = Timer(self.t,self.handle_function)
      self.thread.start()

   def start(self):
      self.thread.start()

   def cancel(self):
      self.thread.cancel()

def timerloop():
   vec = np.arange(0,5,0.01) #time with time step
   for val in np.nditer(vec): 

      if val != 5:
         #print val
         return val

t = perpetualTimer(1,timerloop)
t.start()


class ChangingPlot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #timestep value
        self.inc = 0.01

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

         #[0.2, 0.02, 0.6, 0.03] define the position of the slider
        self.sliderax = self.fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.02, 0.6, 0.03], axisbg='yellow')

        #self.slider = Slider(self.sliderax, 'Value', 0, 10, valinit=self.inc)

        #max to initial value on the slide defined here and increment step is given by self.inc
        self.slider = Slider(self.sliderax, 'Value', 0, 10, valinit=self.inc)
        self.slider.on_changed(self.update)
        x = np.arange(0, 10.5,0.1) #gives the exact increments for the plot dots 
        #can define shape of base graph here
        self.ax.plot(x, 1/x, 'ro') #log graph coordinates
        self.dot, = self.ax.plot(2, 10, 'bo', markersize=18)


    def update(self, value):

        #link to value from slider 
        valuey = int(value / self.inc) * self.inc
        valuex = perpetualTimer(1,timerloop)

        self.dot.set_data([valuex],[valuey])
        self.slider.valtext.set_text('{}'.format(value))
        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def show(self):
        plt.show()

p = ChangingPlot()
p.show()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Its a 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'perpetualTimer' referenced before assignment' which pops up after I run the code and start moving the slider widget. @ppperry

Comment: Amd that `#perpetualTimer = perpetualTimer(1,timerloop)` wasn't commented out when you ran the code and got the error?

Comment: @SilverSlash it was commented out, I've updated that now. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Now what's this `timer = perpetualTimer.timerloop(1,timerloop)` supposed to be?

This makes little to no sense.

Comment: Now I'm guessing `valuex = perpetualTimer(1,timerloop)` here valuex cannot be an object, but rather has to be a float or something.

Comment: @SilverSlash after changing values to int using: ` valuex = int(perpetualTimer(1,timerloop))`, I get the error: AttributeError: perpetualTimer instance has no attribute '__trunc__'.

Comment: Yes, because perpetualTimer(1, timerloop) is an instance of the perpetualTimer class. It cannot be converted to an int!

Comment: Ah I'm not sure how I could change that to a float or an int in that case....any tips on how to go about doing that? @SilverSlash

Comment: Also I've just updated there code and merged the two classes from different files into one. Now I get the Error: 'SystemError: error return without exception set'